# What is the most effective way of sending images to the client applications?

Tags: c#, base64, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an existing REST API developed using ASP.NET WEB API 2,which returns byte[] containing the image responses to the client applications. Apart from byte[] option, we can use base64 string to send as response to the client for getting the image. But base64 format has its own limitations and may not be fit for all kinds of images (i.e. images with different dimensions).

Can any one help me to know is there any other option to return image to the client with good performance?

Comment: Umm, how is encoding affect dimensions of image? It is essentialy a byte array.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2 ?

Comment: An image is a byte array and there is nothing you can do about it. Using Base64 will only make the image representable in ASCII which has zero effect on performance and no value for the user. What you can do to impoove performance is use gzip compression the HTTP stream and/or cache the repsonse for the image requests as images probly do not change often. However those are general tips having nothing to do with the image itself.

Comment: @Magnus does the FileStream result have a preformance impact? In the end it is the same amount of data being send. As far as I understand it only sets the content disposition header.

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev Unless you compress it (usually useless for most images) it is always going to be the same amount of data sent. But you want to stream the result rather than returning a byte[]. To avoid holding the complete data in memory.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your detailed responses. It helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

First, Base64 is pointless in this scenario. The only reason to use it is if you need to include the image in a text-based return format. For example, if you were returning JSON, and you wanted to include the image data as a member of that JSON object, then you would need to Base64 encode. Other than that it does nothing for you. In fact, Base64 will increase the file size roughly 1.5x, since it takes more characters to encode the same data. As a result, you're actually harming performance.

When it comes to alternatives, ultimately everything is essentially a byte array. An image is a binary format, so it's always just a collection of bytes. That said, depending on what you're doing in your action with the image data, you might be better served returning a stream. This will allow the server to directly send the image data down to the client without having to load it into memory first. However, it only works if you're streaming all the way. For example, if you're simply returning a file from the server's filesystem to the client, without modifications, then you can read the file into a stream and return that stream directly. However, if you're manipulating the image, then it will be likely loaded fully into memory regardless, meaning streaming it doesn't really buy you anything. At that point, you can either return a stream or a byte array.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your response. I am using GraphQL.NET to migrate my existing REST APIs to GraphQL resolvers. The existing REST API is sending byte[] as the response to the client applications. On analysis I found that at this point of time, GraphQL.NET is not supporting Byte[] (https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/940). Hence my other option will be sending the data in base64 format. If there are any further good approaches in comparison to what I am trying to do or is there any way that it can be optimized further then in that case please help me to know more details.